# How to make queue duration consistently

Tags: jquery

[sample code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chan15/gjevtw4m/)

```
var liSize = $('li').size();
var duration = 70;
var duration2 = 1000;
var rounds = 43;

$('#start').on('click', function() {
    var index = 0;
    var j = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
        if (i % liSize === 0) {
            index = 0;
        }

        if (i >= rounds - 5) {
            delay = (i * duration) + (j * duration2);
            j++;
        } else {
            delay = i * duration;
        }

        $('li').eq(index).delay(delay).queue(function() {
            var position = $('li').index(this);

            $(this).addClass('on');
            $('li').eq(position - 1).removeClass('on');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });

        index++;
    }

    return false;
});
```

This is how I do to imitate roulette game, `rounds` will be random number, the speed should be the same before the last five box, but it getting slow before the last five, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the first box gets the `on` class, the code has created 43 queues for 10 elements, with 43 different delay durations.

Here's an alternative:  Create each queue *only* when needed – which would be 70ms after a box gets the `on` class (except after 1000ms for the last 5 boxes).

The following does so by defining a `spin()` function, which:

- Processes one box.

  Recursively calls the `spin()` function on the next box.

`rounds` is a parameter (and therefore a local variable) in the `spins()` function.  Its value is decremented in each recursive call, and the `spins()` function is no longer called when it reaches zero.

```
$('#start').on('click', function() {
  var rounds = 43;

  function spin(li, rounds) {
    var duration = rounds<5 ? 1000 : 70;

    $('li').stop(true);

    li.delay(duration).queue(function() {
      var nextBox= $(this).next('li');
      if(!nextBox.length) {
        nextBox= $('li:first');
      }

      $('li').removeClass('on');
      $(this).addClass('on');
      if(rounds-1) {
        spin(nextBox, rounds-1);
      }
    });
  } //spin

  spin($('li:first'), rounds);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vo3wht2/1/)

Comment: May I ask one more question, this function basically set 43 times to li with 70 duration at once, why was it executed effect one by one?

Comment: The call to `spin` creates only one queue.  After the duration, `spin` runs again, which creates the next queue.  So there's only one queue running at any time, compared to 43 queues that were running with your code.  (Note that the duration changes to 1000 when rounds reaches 5.)

Comment: `move` might be a better name for the `spin` function, because it processes only one box at a time.